# mediawiki DBTransactionStateError

Tags: php, mysql, module, mediawiki

getting below error while importing mediawiki modules to website:
mediawiki version - 1.34.2
mysql: Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.17-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
php: PHP 7.3.22 (cli) (built: Sep 1 2020 09:44:58) ( NTS )

2020-09-24 14:15:30 blackwiki.org blackwikinew: [22b8687edf9dc58ad4162e17] /index.php?title=Special:Import&action=submit   Wikimedia\Rdbms\DBTransactionStateError from line 1420 of /usr/share/nginx/html/mediawiki/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php: Cannot execute query from Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database::ping while transaction status is ERROR
#0 /usr/share/nginx/html/mediawiki/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(1145): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->assertQueryIsCurrentlyAllowed(string, string)
#1 /usr/share/nginx/html/mediawiki/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(4297): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->query(string, string, integer)
#2 /usr/share/nginx/html/mediawiki/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(687): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->ping(NULL)
#3 /usr/share/nginx/html/mediawiki/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(677): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->pingAndCalculateLastTrxApplyTime()
#4 /usr/share/nginx/html/mediawiki/includes/libs/rdbms/loadbalancer/LoadBalancer.php(1605): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->pendingWriteQueryDuration(string)
#5 /usr/share/nginx/html/mediawiki/includes/libs/rdbms/loadbalancer/LoadBalancer.php(2109): Wikimedia\Rdbms\LoadBalancer->Wikimedia\Rdbms{closure}(Wikimedia\Rdbms\DatabaseMysqli)
#6 /usr/share/nginx/html/mediawiki/includes/libs/rdbms/loadbalancer/LoadBalancer.php(1621): Wikimedia\Rdbms\LoadBalancer->forEachOpenMasterConnection(Closure)
#7 /usr/share/nginx/html/mediawiki/includes/libs/rdbms/lbfactory/LBFactory.php(208): Wikimedia\Rdbms\LoadBalancer->approveMasterChanges(array, string, integer)
#8 /usr/share/nginx/html/mediawiki/includes/libs/rdbms/lbfactory/LBFactorySimple.php(134): Wikimedia\Rdbms\LBFactory->Wikimedia\Rdbms{closure}(Wikimedia\Rdbms\LoadBalancer, string, array)
#9 /usr/share/nginx/html/mediawiki/includes/libs/rdbms/lbfactory/LBFactory.php(210): Wikimedia\Rdbms\LBFactorySimple->forEachLB(Closure, array)
#10 /usr/share/nginx/html/mediawiki/includes/libs/rdbms/lbfactory/LBFactory.php(269): Wikimedia\Rdbms\LBFactory->forEachLBCallMethod(string, array)
#11 /usr/share/nginx/html/mediawiki/includes/MediaWiki.php(611): Wikimedia\Rdbms\LBFactory->commitMasterChanges(string, array)
#12 /usr/share/nginx/html/mediawiki/includes/MediaWiki.php(582): MediaWiki::preOutputCommit(RequestContext, Closure)
#13 /usr/share/nginx/html/mediawiki/includes/MediaWiki.php(916): MediaWiki->doPreOutputCommit(Closure)
#14 /usr/share/nginx/html/mediawiki/includes/MediaWiki.php(527): MediaWiki->main()
#15 /usr/share/nginx/html/mediawiki/index.php(44): MediaWiki->run()
#16 {main}

Let me know if anyone having idea regardin this.

thanks

Comment: That should probably be filed as a bug. There is some sort of SQL error, but the transaction management logic mishandles it and generates a new error so the details of the original error are obscured.

Comment: thanks, true maybe but then how can i fix this issue,

Comment: becuase for debug and try i already tried and setup erro logs also,
but in that also above error seems nothing changes,  in debug log there are too much big logs not able to understand, in that also at the end we get above error.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the real error. This one is just about the DB framework trying to get metrics while the transaction is in an error state.